# How do I loop through this array?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Well I'm relatively new to the use of PHP arrays and I have the follow array I need to loop through this array 2280 and 2307 are the identifiers.

I'm find it hard trying to come up with a foreach() that collects all the data.

```
Array
(
[2280] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://deals.com.au//uploads/deal_image/2706.jpg
        [1] => Yuan's Massage and Beauty
        [2] => Get Hair Free in CBD! Only $99 for SIX MONTHS worth of the latest in IPL Permanent Hair Reduction. Choose which area you want treated! Valued at $900 from Yuan's Massage and Beauty in the Heart of Melbourne's CBD. Limited vouchers available
        [3] => 99
        [4] => 900
        [5] => 801
        [6] => http://deals.com.au/1827
    )

[2307] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://deals.com.au//uploads/deal_image/2683.jpg
        [1] => Name Necklace Australia
        [2] => Style yourself like SJP! Only $29 for a STERLING Silver Name Necklace plus get FREE delivery! Valued at $75 with NameNecklace.com.au
        [3] => 29
        [4] => 75
        [5] => 46
        [6] => http://deals.com.au/Melbourne
    )
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do apart from a `foreach`? Are there any specific parts of the array elements that you're not understanding how to access?

Comment: I just want to be able to beable to access it for instance $array[0] will access the first [0] and for fourth

Comment: What did you try? And what is the problem?

Comment: I don't work with PHP very much, but shouldn't each one of those values (except for the numbers) be enclosed with parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array snippet

```
$array = array( // foreach ($array as $k=>$subarray)
'2280' /* this is your $k */ => 
    array( /* and this is your $subarray */
        'http://deals.com.au//uploads/deal_image/2706.jpg',
```

And now you get data you need (you had to use nested `foreach` since values of your array are arrays):

```
foreach ($array as $k=>$subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $data) {
        echo $data;//of subarray
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The OPs comment quistion on my answer:

> what if I wanted to be selective rather than get a massive data dump. 
>   if I echo $data how do I access specific rows?

Well, in most cases you should associate keys and data in your array (we call it associative array in PHP).

Example 1:

```
$hex_colors = array('FF0000', '00FF00' '0000FF');
```

Values are not assoiated with correspondent keys. PHP will assign 0,1,2... keys to arrays elements itself. In this case you would get green color's heximal value using auto-assigned by `PHP` 1 key: `echo $hex_colors[1]; // 00FF00` and of course you should know it for sure. Usually this approach is used when you have strict data structure like `array(red, green, bluee)`, but in most cases you better use the  following approach:

Example 2:

```
$hex_colors = array('red'=>'FF0000', 'green'=>'00FF00' 'blue'=>'0000FF');
```

heximal colors representations are associated with appropriate keys `echo $hex_colors['green']; // 00FF00`

If your array was:

```
$array = array(
    '2280' => array(
        'image_url' => 'http://deals.com.au//uploads/deal_image/2706.jpg',
        'product_name' => 'Yuan\'s Massage and Beauty',
        'description' => 'Get Hair Free in CBD! Only $99 for SIX MONTHS worth of the latest in IPL Permanent Hair Reduction. Choose which area you want treated! Valued at $900 from Yuan's Massage and Beauty in the Heart of Melbourne's CBD. Limited vouchers available',
        'price' => 99,
        'weight_brutto' => 900,
        'weight_netto' => 801,
        'dealer_store' => 'http://deals.com.au/1827',
        ...
```

You would be able to access data using, let's call it "human-readable" keys:

```
foreach ($array as $id=>$product) {
    echo '<a href="http://myshop.com/?product_id='.$id.'">Buy '.$product['name'].'</a>';
    echo '<img class="product_thumbnail" src="'.$product['image_url'].'" />';
    echo 'Description: '.$product['description'];
    echo 'The price is '.number_format($product['price']);
    ...
}
```

It is well-suited for reading rows from database, for example:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_result_link, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
// MYSQL_ASSOC flag is not necessary
// PHP will use this flag by default for mysql_fetch_array function
// keys of $data will be correspondent columns names returned by mysql query
    echo $data['id'];
    echo $data['title'];
    ...
}
```

Continue learning `PHP` and you will find many more situations when it's more convenient to associate keys and values.

Comment: It might be easier to read (in this case) if you don't include the array definition. Just the `foreach` loop seems sufficient to me.

Comment: Thanks you. I tried to make my answer comprehansive for `PHP` beginners, so I've left the initial array snippet to show how nested `foreach` works and removed the unnecessary part

Comment: Hi, but what if I wanted to be selective rather than get a massive data dump if I echo $data how do I access specific rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {

    //$key1==2280; $value1 is the array
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        //$key2==0;$value2="http://deals.com.au//uploads/deal_image/2706.jpg"
    }

}
```

Comment: this is WRONG -- what is `$arr2` -- change it to `$value1`

Comment: The nested arrays are not key/value pairs, so your code is a bit odd unless for some reason they want the indexes.